# How to configure batchscript to parallelize R script with future.batchtools (SLURM)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, hpc, slurm

I seek to parallize an R file on an SLURM HPC using the future.batchtools packages. While the script is executed on multiple nodes, it only use 1 CPU instead of 12 that are available.

So far, I tried different configurations (c.f. code attached) which do not lead to the expected results. My bash file with the configuration is as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=12

R CMD BATCH test.R output
```

In R, I use a foreach loop:

```
# First level = cluster
# Second level = multiprocess 
# https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/future.batchtools/vignettes/future.batchtools.html
plan(list(batchtools_slurm, multiprocess))

# Parallel for loop
result <- foreach(i in 100) %dopar% {
       Sys.sleep(100)
return(i) 
}
```

I would appreciate if someone can give me guidance on how to configure the code for multiple nodes and multiple cores.

Comment: Your R script uses a single layer of foreach parallelization, which will parallelize using `batchtools_slurm`. If you use two layers of foreach parallelization, the second layer will use multiprocess (given that `plan()`).   FYI, `foreach(i in 100)` will only iterate over a single value.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I actually use a nested forachach with this plan (I didn't paste it here for the sake of a parsimonious example.
```R
result <- foreach(i= 1:100) %dopar% {
  foreach(jRun = 1:100) %dopar% { 
# calulation
}}
```
This code is closer to the one I am using. Still, I do not exploit multiple knots on the HPC. Is there anything else I am overlooking?

Comment: Ah... you need to specify the number of cores per task when you set up the plan - something like `plan(list(tweak(batchtools_slurm, resources = list("ntasks-per-node"=4)), multiprocess))`, cf. https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future.batchtools.  To verify that this works: With that new plan, call `f <- future( availableCores() ); ncores <- value(f)`.  That will show how many cores the second layer will have available. You should get four (4).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
For others, who face the same challenge: it is necessary to start the .R files with srun in order to allow parallel processes.

Comment: Michael, did you manage to find the right setup in the end? If so, how about posting the solution you found here?

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways of parallelizing R jobs with Slurm. A few to note:

1. You can use a single node with multiple cores, in which case `mclapply` is one nice alternative to use since in principle is faster and more memmory efficient compared to, say, `parLapply`.
2. You can use [JOB arrays with Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html), meaning that you can write a single R script that Slurm will run multiple times specifying the option `--array=1-[# of replicates]`. You can specify what to do within each job using the `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` environment variable (you can capture that in R using `Sys.getenv("SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID")`). And use conditionals `if/else` statement based on that.
3. @george-ostrouchov mentioned, you can use MPI for which you would need to have the [Rmpi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpi/index.html) package installed, but that may be a bit painful some times.
4. Another thing you can try is creating a SOCKET cluster object using the parallel package. This would be a multi-node cluster which would allow you spanning your calculations using `parLapply` and others across multiple nodes.

I do have a tutorial in which I explain these options and how can you use the `slurmR` package (which I'm working on, soon on CRAN) or the `rslurm` (which is already on CRAN). You can take a look at the tutorial [here](https://uscbiostats.github.io/slurmr-workshop).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running in batch and using more than one node, consider combining MPI with `mclapply`'s multicore fork. These are closer to what actually happens in hardware and provide control between the number of R instances per node and core use of each instance. Example SLURM and PBS scripts and an accompanying R batch script are in https://github.com/RBigData/mpi_balance, illustrating how to balance multicore and multinode parallelism.